# How to find Date between two date columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have two tables in excel, first with columnA (date),columnB(date), and second table columnC(date),columnD(values), i want to highlight Cells from columnD(values)
if columnC(date) is between columnA and columnB?
What i try is with this formula:
 `=IF(AND(A2>$B$1,A2<$c$1),a2, FALSE)`
but i don't get any result?

What i expect is this:[image]

Comment: You could try using =DATEDIF(start_date, end_date, unit) to get the number representing the time between the dates.

Comment: `=AND(B1>A1, C1<B1)`

Comment: @KenWhite Ha WAY simpler than mine, whoops.

Comment: @oxwilder: It is. :-) It's much more readable too.

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>i want to highlight Cells from columnD(values) **if columnC(date) is between columnA and columnB**     `=IF(AND(A2>$B$1,A2<$c$1),a2, FALSE)`</sub>

Your narrative contradicts the supplied formula. For a conditional formatting rule on columnD, base it on this formula.

```
=and(c2>=min(a2, b2), c2<=max(a2, b2))
```

A CFR formula need only return true or false. This formula can be tested by putting it in E2 and filling down.

Comment: please see my question again

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the column you want the highlighting to appear in and type this formula into the conditional formatting formula field:

```
=if(and(c2>a2,c2<b2),true,false)=true
```

Remember to set your formatting options so the cells appear different.
Good luck!

Comment: If the full column is to receive the CFR then those should be A1, B1 and C1. Also, your boolean definition is redundant.

Comment: @jeeped I assumed the OP was using headers, but as for redundancy, yeah belt and braces.

Comment: Please see what i want like result

Comment: @spec Well now my redundancy is just what we needed. Paste the formula `=if(and(c2>a2,c2<b2),a2)` in F2 and copy it down.

Comment: Please look carefully again,probobly, need loop  for columnC to check between columnA and ColumnB???